# How do I convert these commands to work in a conky file?

Tags: text-processing, conky, math

What I am doing is working on a conky widget, and I am trying to get a voltage reading from the sensor chip on my motherboard to display it. I am getting a voltage reading and displaying it in the widget like this:

```
${execi 1 sensors -u | grep -w 'in6_input'|cut -c 14-32}
```

This returns the value of that input line correctly, which is `2.032`. However, that is a reference voltage output from a voltage divider on the motherboard, since the inputs on the chip can not handle anything over 4V directly. Unfortunately, this motherboard doesn't do the math and sends it out as an actual voltage reading. So I need to do the math to get it back to 12.1V (approx. what the BIOS shows).

I can make the math work from a command prompt as below:

```
~$ twelve=$(sensors -u | grep -w "in6_input"|cut -c 14-32)
~$ echo "scale=3;$twelve*(67300/11300)" | bc -l
12.148
```

So what I am asking is

1. How (if possible) to integrate this into the conky template?** and
2. <strike>how do I make the output only display 3 decimal places?</strike>

**EDIT:** One of the problems has been solved (thank you steeldriver). Edited the title to be more specific to the remaining question.

Comment: You can use bc's `scale` statement to set the number of decimal places it returns. See for example [GNU bc Command: Examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC19)

Comment: Thanks! I'll got check it out now..

Comment: Ok, it looks like I found a work-around. I just made a bash script to handle it. I know most folks call lua scripts with conky but this was just a quick fix... But by all means, if there are other answers for me (and I know there are) keep em coming. Hopefully I'll learn something.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is often useful in these situations as it is quite powerful so can replace several of the commands:

```
${execi 1 sensors -u | awk '/in6_input:/{printf "%.3f",$2*(67300/11300)}'}
```

`$2` means the 2nd word in the line (splitting on whitespace). `%.3f` is the float format with 3 decimals (after the ".").